# Can I set_markup to a PopupMenuItem?

Tags: gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

Since a Label in a PopupMenuItem, I thinks it can be set a pango text here.

> PopupMenuItem: A PopupBaseMenuItem that displays text in a St.Label.

```
const item = new PopupMenu.PopupMenuItem("");
item.actor.set_size(300,150);   <--- effect.
item.actor.create_pango_layout('<span foreground="blue" size="32">fname</span>');  <- not effect
item.actor.set_markup('<span foreground="blue" size="32">fname</span>'); <-- fail, but it worked in vala.
```

I read `popupMenu.js` source code before, but now I forgot the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to set this on the internal `Clutter.Text` of the `PopupMenu.PopupMenuItems`'s `St.Label`:

```js
const item = new PopupMenu.PopupMenuItem('');

item.label.clutter_text.set_markup(
  '<span foreground="blue" size="32">fname</span>');
```

You can bookmark this link to the whole directory of GNOME Shell's UI:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/tree/main/js/ui

Comment: St.Label.clutter-text is readonly refer to (https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/st10~1.0_api/st.label). Maybe St.Label is not same as Gtk.Label.

Comment: It works now. thanks. the `size` has no effect.  `font_desc` take effect.